# OAuth token invalid: Error 2500

Tags: android, facebook

I am having a recurring problem while using Facebook OAuth methods. Despite trying my own implementation everything is supposed to be compliant and dialogs are working fine, but I keep getting error 2500 when I tried to do requests. My login code, called in oncreate, is as follows:

```
mPrefs = m_kActivity.getPreferences(m_kActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        m_kFacebookClient.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        m_kFacebookClient.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(!m_kFacebookClient.isSessionValid()) {

    m_kFacebookClient.authorize(m_kActivity, new String[] {
            "publish_stream", "read_stream" },
            new Facebook.DialogListener() { // OVERLOADS }
    }
```

and my publish method, done in onCreate too, is

```
byte[] data = null;
    String dataPath = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0001.3gp";
    String dataMsg = "TestStuff";
    String dataName = "VIDEO0001.3gp";

    Bundle param;
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(m_kFacebookClient);
    InputStream is = null;
        is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        data = readBytes(is);
        param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("message", dataMsg);
        param.putByteArray("video", data);
        param.putString("filename", dataName);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", param, "POST",
                new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() { // OVERLOAD }
```

I tried getting the token info and it is correct:

```
05-15 14:53:17.149: D/myapp(7964): access token = AAACmjJqKCmMBAFRMjn49t7DvXEPlRyKnbdghdthdth31654651oGGJnBpSxEiLb5R3ZAxEEoI0x4JAfCvnQWIyK08cmzUGqX1I2IeeyV
05-15 14:53:17.149: D/myapp(7964): expiration = 1337090401151
05-15 14:53:17.169: D/myapp(7964): expiration datetime = Tue May 15 16:00:01 CEST 2012
05-15 14:53:17.169: D/myapp(7964): is session valid? true
05-15 14:54:48.849: D/myapp(7964): {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

EDIT: If I add "offline_access" permission the token becomes erroneous.

```
05-15 15:24:06.639: D/myapp(8180): expiration = 0
05-15 15:24:06.669: D/myapp(8180): expiration datetime = Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
05-15 15:24:06.679: D/myapp(8180): is session valid? true
```

As for the behaviour, it never asks me to log in after I logged the first time. If I uninstall it from the phone I need to log in again, and if I delete the App from my FB account it asks for all permissions again. Dialogs are working fine too.

Comment: check your token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - it is invalid. Probably a character is cut off?

Comment: Issued: 1337088246 (4 minutes ago)

Expires: Never

Valid: True

Origin: Mobile Web Faceweb

Scopes: create_note offline_access photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update video_upload

Comment: the token from your post does not work. Do you have another one? Also - is it app token or user token?

Comment: I manually edited the token before posting so nobody else could use it :) The debug gives me both appid and userid but I don't know if it's app or user token. I retrieve it using myFacebook.getAccessToken()

Comment: expire: Never suggests to me that this is app token. Can you try mAsyncRunner.request("<YOUR_USER_ID>", .. instead of mAsyncRunner.request("me", ?

Comment: Different error, thats a good sign: {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}

Comment: oh - you are not passing token at all :) you need to correct your code - probably put it into params Bundle

Comment: Can you give me a snippet of the changes, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you are not setting access token at all. Try this please:

```
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, m_kFacebookClient.getAccessToken());
```

Comment: 100: "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app". I do not have access to app configuration :(

Comment: i guess your app is still in test mode then. I would suggest you create completely new app - which you will have full control on, and debug your program against it - and when all is done and working, you will only have to replace APP_ID in your app, and that should be it. But you have to have the control of the app during development. It will make things much easier.

Comment: It *should't* be because it's an already released app (hence why I'm editing my tokens) and users can join and whatnot.

Comment: Amnyway, why can I create new posts using dialogs but not using requests?

Comment: Apparently I needed param.putString("name", videoName); also.